# Google Cloud Platform: "Update Google Stackdriver monitoring agent"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

We are using Google Cloud Platform for our solution, and we have hundreds of vm's running in multiple projects, as part of a change in Stackdriver alerting system, Google has requested to upgrade monitoring agent in all the VM's by running :-

```
sudo apt-get install stackdriver-agent 
sudo /opt/stackdriver/stack-config --write-gcm
```

Is the any script or utility which I use to run the upgrade commands on all VM's at a time rather than ssh into each one and run individually.

Also while running the command "`sudo apt-get install stackdriver-agent`", asks for a 
"`API key for use with Stackdriver`"  - "`Stackdriver requires an API key to submit metrics. You can get an API key from https://app.stackdriver.com/settings/`"

Is there any way to provide this key as well in the script or utility.

Comment: I did something like `for instance in $(cat my_instances)
do
    file=$(gcloud compute ssh $instance --command '<command to execute>') 
done` with `my_instances` the list of instance names (obtained via `gcloud compute instances list`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `--write-gcm`, the API key is no longer needed, so you can just leave it blank in the install script. You're seeing a bit of legacy code shining through -- apologies for the confusion.

As far as upgrading multiple VMs at once, Google doesn't provide a ready solution, but you can use one of the popular configuration management tools (e.g., Puppet, Chef, Salt, Ansible) to script such an upgrade. There are [(somewhat stale) solutions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#automated_installation) for Puppet, Chef, and Ansible available that you can try to adapt for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use mussh to execute the commands against multiple ssh host in parallel.